# Float image Left of text and paragraph while keeping everything responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Using Bootstrap 3.03, I am trying to have a responsive img float left and have two headings and two paragraphs wrap to the right of the image, and one always stay on the bottom left while everything remains responsive, like the following image:

[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="amanda" >
      <img  id="amandaimg" text-align="left" class="img-responsive" src=""/>

       <div id="rightb">
        <h1 id="bheading"> Heading 1</h1>
        <h1 id="pheading"> Heading 2</h1>
          <p id="bp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inermis denique verterem ex vel. Has ne iisque detracto. Ea eum utinam labores. Quot dolorem mea et, omnis eleifend no per. In verear meliore vivendo pro, nec in rebum suscipit lobortis, laudem melius assueverit vix at. Ei ius modo tempor fuisset, sit eu noster vidisse moderatius, cu cibo minim argumentum mea. Vix enim purto appellantur eu, sea illud corpora efficiendi ut. No vix tota ullum legendos, nec veri omnium cu, dicat verear impetus cu vis. Ne quas laoreet his.
          </p>
            <p id="bp">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inermis denique verterem ex vel. Has ne iisque detracto. Ea eum utinam labores. Quot dolorem mea et, omnis eleifend no per. In verear meliore vivendo pro, nec in rebum suscipit lobortis, laudem melius assueverit vix at. Ei ius modo tempor fuisset, sit eu noster vidisse moderatius, cu cibo minim argumentum mea. Vix enim purto appellantur eu, sea illud corpora efficiendi ut. No vix tota ullum legendos, nec veri omnium cu, dicat verear impetus cu vis. Ne quas laoreet his.
            </p>  
          </div>
           <div id="leftb" class="col-md-8"><p id="op">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, inermis denique verterem ex vel. Has ne iisque detracto. Ea eum utinam labores. Quot dolorem mea et, omnis eleifend no per. In verear meliore vivendo pro, nec in rebum suscipit lobortis, laudem melius assueverit vix at. Ei ius modo tempor fuisset, sit eu noster vidisse moderatius, cu cibo minim argumentum mea. Vix enim purto appellantur eu, sea illud corpora efficiendi ut. No vix tota ullum legendos, nec veri omnium cu, dicat verear impetus cu vis. Ne quas laoreet his.

          </p>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
       #amanda {margin-top:-30px;background-image: url();min-height:600px;max-width:945px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;  }

      #bheading {color:#fff;font-size:33px;margin-top:20px;padding-left:30px;float:left; margin-bottom:4px;width:500px;}
      #pheading {color:#fff;font-size:22px;float:left;margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:12px;width:300px;}
      #rightb {  text-align:left;}
      #leftb { float:left; clear:both;}
      #bp {text-indent:20px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;max-width:470px; padding-top:8px;padding-left:30px;float:left; text-align:left;}
      #amandaimg {width:350px; height:329px;float:left;margin-top:28px;margin-left:30px;}
```

I'm running into a ton of trouble with the above code...what am I doing wrong/what can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this with a little bit of fiddling around:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbavvg2h/1/

The jist of it is that you want the image to be in one div, and then the headers and paragraphs besides the bottom one to be in a second div.

```
<div><img></img></div>
<div><h1></h1><h1></h1><p></p></div>
```

Have these two divs be

```
display:inline-block; 
vertical-align:top;
```

In order to get them to align properly and side by side, no float necessary. Then you have another div after for the bottom paragraph. Then you can tweak min/max widths, container widths, margins, font sizes, and all of that to your likings.

Comment: This is definitely such a solid way of accomplishing this responsively. It works for me perfectly.